# How do I get the city name out of this?

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, location

I hhave this in the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Geolocation</title>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="funciones.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<button id="startGeo">Click here to check your geolocation abilities</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have this in a function.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startGeo").click(checkLocation);

function checkLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation,locationFailed);
        //document.write("you have geolocation");
    }
    else {
        document.write("you don't have geolocation");
    }
}//ends checkLocation()

function getLocation(position){
    var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
    var exactitud = position.coords.accuracy;

    alert("latitud: " + latitud + " longitud: " + longitud + " exactitud: " + exactitud);
    //document.write("we received your location");
}   
function locationFailed(){
    document.write("we didn't get your location. Please check your settings");
}
});
```

from this I get the coordinates, but I have no idea at all on how to get the city name... or the state name. I saw a question similar to this answered but they seemed to be using json. I don't want a map, just the info, it can be text or an alert. Please any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reverse Geocoding API

Sample call:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=50.123413,-22.12345&sensor=true

You can replace your getLocation function like that (make appropriate tests before accessing data.results[2]):

```
function getLocation(position){
    var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
    var exactitud = position.coords.accuracy;

    $.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitud + ',' + longitud + '&sensor=true', function(data) {
        alert(data.results[2].address_components[0].long_name);
    });

    //alert("latitud: " + latitud + " longitud: " + longitud + " exactitud: " + exactitud);
    //document.write("we received your location");
}
```

You can check the following fiddle to see it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/5tzxks10/

Comment: thank you so much for this. indeed thanks to your help I get the info, but the wrong one, it gives me an address I don't know. Is that maybe a problem with the json in the api? I ran other codes and it gives me different locations depending the browser I use. 

I wonder if this might have something to do with the data.results[2]. If that's the case, how can I know which one to use?

Comment: Indeed it depends on the data results[2] I put 2 here just as an example

Comment: Please check out the API doc to know better about the response:

Comment: thank you, I understand way more. However (i asked this in an answer but idk if it will get to you) where can I see the different results?? is there a page?

Answer (score 0):

+Nowres Rafed I changed your code a little bit:

```
function getLocation(position){
var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
var exactitud = position.coords.accuracy;

$.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitud + ',' + longitud, function(data) {
    alert(data.results[1].formatted_address);
});

//alert("latitud: " + latitud + " longitud: " + longitud + " exactitud: " + exactitud);
//document.write("we received your location");
```

it gives more information that way. Thank you so much. What I would like to know (if it's possible) is where can I read or know how to fetch a specific answer, I read that when you get the results, it returns more than one result. I changed the number as you mentioned, testing the different options. But, is there somewhere where I can look for those results? forgive the bother, I'm just new to this.